# How to make a working navigation menu that transition from top when clicked on hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to design a hamburger menu that lets users tap on while using phones and tablets but switch to the full nav bar on the desktop. I have a working navbar for desktop but I have not been able to make one for phones/tablets. I have made a checkbox to try implementing it. But when the checkbox(ham menu) is clicked, it doesn't do anything. Also, tried with negative values. If anyone can help me, I would appreciate it a lot.

Here's my code:

```css
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap");
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: aliceblue;
    }
    header {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 20px 8%;
      background-color: #2f2e41;
      top: 0;
      color: aliceblue;
      width: auto;
      .nav-links,
      li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
      .nav-links li a {
        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
      }
      .nav-links li a:hover {
        color: #6e00ff;
      }
    }
    input[type="checkbox"] {
      display: none;
    }
    header .navMode .menu {
      display: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 420px) {
      header nav .nav-links {
        background: #2f2e41;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        height: 30vh;
        width: 100%;
        right: 0%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
        li {
          margin-top: 5px;
          padding: 10px 0;
          a:hover {
            color: #6e00ff;
            background: none;
          }
        }
      }
      header .navMode .menu{
        display: block;
      }
      #click:checked ~ .menuBar i:before {
        content: "\f00d";
      }
      #click:checked ~ .menuBar .nav-links {
        top: 0%;
      }
      header nav i {
        font-size: 20px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <p>Name</p>
      </a>
      <nav class="navMode">
        <div class="menu">
          <input type="checkbox" id="click">
          <label for="click" class="menuBar">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </label>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
          <li> <a class="navBar-links" href="#">Lorem
            </a></li>
          <li> <a class="navBar-links" href="#">Lorem
            </a></li>
          <li> <a class="navBar-links" href="#">Lorem
            </a></li>
          <li> <a class="navBar-links" href="#">lorem
            </a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Take a look at this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jo_Geek/pen/xgbaEr) it will solve your problem.